# How do I get the 'On A Rail' achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm a little confused by the On A Rail achievement in minecraft. Do I need to go to a point 1km manhattan/euclidean distance from where I started. Or If I went down 500m of track went back 500m of different track and ended up 2-3 meters from where I started would that count?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you have to travel 1000m (=1000 blocks) from the point where you started in **one direction**.
The rails can go up and down but they have to go a 1000 blocks in one direction.

What I mean is that, you can divert from the path, but you have to have travelled 1000 blocks in one direction.

Let's say there are directions W,X,Y,Z.

<kbd>W</kbd> = Forward

<kbd>X</kbd> = Backward

<kbd>Y</kbd> = Right

<kbd>Z</kbd> = Left

Now, if you want to go 1000m in <kbd>W</kbd> direction, you can divert and go a bit <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, but they will not be counted, similarly, <kbd>X</kbd> will also not be counted. You need to travel 1000 blocks only in <kbd>W</kbd> direction.

Comment: I still don't quite understand, do you mean they have to go 1000 blocks in either the x or z direction, an order zero length so to speak?

Comment: I've edited it, now do you understand?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be very accurate. Today I just built a rail to NW direction, and offset X,Z is 700,300 and I still get the achievement. http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Achievement_Guide#On_a_Rail_.28Travel_by_minecart_at_least_1km_from_where_you_started..29

Comment: Does being in creative mode count?

Answer (score 10):

It does not have to be in a single direction as others have pointed out but you have to end up over 1000 blocks or meters as the crow flies from your starting point.

For example: if you travel 820 blocks west and 550 blocks south this will not work since your end location is 988 blocks from where you began. If you traveled 20 blocks further west you would get the achievement since you are now 1004 blocks from your starting point.

Comment: In other words it's the euclidean distance that matters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a huge track in a straight line that goes on for about 1000 blocks. The track can't have any turns or bends and so it has to be a straight line in any direction. You must then ride the track and don't get out until the end. sometimes you need to make it a bit longer than 1000 blocks (i done 1129 blocks long). You are unable to earn achievements in a world that has previously been saved in creative mode.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can get the achievement so long as you have moved 1000 blocks from your start location in one of the four directions (North, East, South, or West). You do have to get out and back in again at the start (which is part of what I was doing wrong).

Answer (score 0):

It takes a lot more track than you would expect, 1000 blocks is a lot. You can make like a roller coaster, but the end point must be at least 1000 blocks away from where you started. Otherwise it will not work. In my opinion, doing that achievement would have to lead up to getting something good. Another way to figure it out is to go into the stats option and look at distance by minecart. If it is 14.56 then when you are done with your ride it would have to be 15.56 or more.

Comment: You can always rip up the rail if you really want. However, your suggestion about looking in the stats is inaccurate. You must go 1000 blocks in one of the cardinal directions (North, East, South or West). If you have a zig-zag or something this will still increase your distance without counting towards your 1000 block requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You must travel 1,000 blocks North, South, East or West from the starting point. You can turn left or right from the chosen direction, but you cannot go back the way you came. Turning left or right does not count toward the qouta, but it does not subtract either. Zigzagging will count towards both chosen directions, but it is a slower process.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ride the rails until you are 1000 blocks from where you started, in Euclidean distance.

Comment: As the crow flies isn't a good description.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @TimmyJim “As the crow flies” may be idiomatic, but [its meaning is precise and unambiguous, and it's widely used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_crow_flies).

Comment: This is just repeating the first line of Bstewart's answer from 3 years ago

Comment: by "as the crow flies" I mean distance in any direction, so 3 meters east and 4 meters north is 5 meters as the crow flies from where you began

Comment: @I.Golsby I'm sorry, but "as the crow flies" is not at all descriptive of what you're trying to say (which seems to be euclidean distance). Also, as Angzuril pointed out, you don't seem to have added anything.

Comment: @CrazyCasta It's a common phrase, I don't see why it's so controversial. Also I added this because I felt the other answers were too complex and what we needed was just a simple straightforward answer that answered the question and only THAT question.

Comment: Well, it's too simple and doesn't answer the question. Sorry.

Comment: @CrazyCasta it answers the question exactly. All the asker wanted was how to earn it, and I provided them with that information. Heavy elaboration is not necessary to answer a simple question.

Comment: There. I removed the 'confusing' phrase so you guys should be a bit happier.

Answer (score -3):

Don't you just have to travel the total amount of blocks in any direction including what you have already passed eg using 8 rails and going in a circle-ish travel. This works in Captive Minecraft (map)

Comment: This works in captive minecraft because they did some command block magic. Normally, you need to travel 1000 blocks from where you started in one direction.